# Data not appending to url when sending through Jquery and Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

Ive created a simple backbone.js app to check how it works.
The application lets user search for a book by title in MySQL database.
The application contains a text field and a button as such,

```
 <input type="text" id="search" name="title"><be>
 <button id="searchBtn">Search</button>
```

What I want is to send the data to the codeigniter 3 backend and get data related to the searched book.For sending the search keyword, Ive created a jquery function,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#searchBtn").click(function() {
            var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
                url: function() {
                    var urlstr = "/tutorials/t5/todociapp/index.php/Restapi/book?title=" + this.get("title");
                    return urlstr;
                },
                idAttribute: "id",
                defaults: {
                    title: null,
                    author: null
                }
            });
            var book1 = new Book({
                "title": "Book1",
                // author:"Author1"
            });
            book1.fetch({
                async: false,
                success: function() {
                    alert("HEYYYY!" + book1.get('title'))
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

I'm trying to append the searched keyword to the end of the URL and get the value from the backend using segments.

```
    public function book_get()
{
    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'GET') {
        // $search = $this->input->get("search");
        $search = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $book = $this->BookModel->getBookByTitle($search);
        log_message('debug', "HEYYYYY");
        log_message('debug', $search);
        print json_encode($book);
    } elseif ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {
        log_message('debug', "HEYYYYY POST");
        $data = $this->decode_data($this->input->raw_input_stream);
        $title = $data['title'];
        $author = $data['author'];
        $addBook = $this->BookModel->addBookToDB($title,$author);
        echo json_encode($addBook);
    }
}
```

My problem is the searched keyword doesn't append to the end of the URL and if possible tell me how to display the author name for the searched book in the alert box.